# How to grey out section of content or put image "on top" to hide

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm using a WordPress plugin where I simply enter a shortcode for the page to generate. I want to grey out a small section of the content that appears. Is there some html code I can add to the WordPress page to do this? Ideally I would then add something like "this section is for pro members only". Alternatively, is there a way I can add a fixed image so it sits "on top" of that section of the page so what's underneath is not visible?

Comment: Placing something over content in the DOM to hide it isn't secure.  Anyone can open the dev tools and remove the "cover", or simply view what's under it in the dev tools.

Comment: I'm not too concerned about that as what's underneath isn't classified information and most people won't bother with that. I just want to either grey it out or at least add some image to cover it.

Comment: What's the markup look like?  How are you determining if it should be greyed out or not?

Comment: I am using the same shortcode on two pages - I want to hide just one small section on the second page. So was thinking that surely I could add some image "on top" of the content or maybe find some plugin that would add some fixed content "on top" of what loads on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh...My favourite kind of question!!!

usually i create one class for hiddencontent for just grey out purpose.
so you can apply that hidden class for any div or container tag and it will work to grey out content and background.

But remember this will only work for new browsers. these details you can find on below websites.
[Can I use?](http://caniuse.com/#feat=user-select-none)

[Mozilla Developer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select)

Sample Codepen below

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rjewpd

```
HTML
<div class="mainContainer hiddenContent">
  hi i am content.
</div>

CSS
.mainContainer
{
  background:aqua;
}
.hiddenContent
{
   -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome/Safari/Opera */
     -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror */
       -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
        -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
            user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                  not supported by any browser */
  opacity:0.2;
  background:#bbb;
}
```